# Prove that the eigenvalues of $3 \times 3$ orthogonal symmetric matrix are $\pm 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be an orthogonal symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix. Prove that its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$

I think you would start the proof by saying that $Av = \lambda v $ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ and the corresponding eigenvector $v$.

then, $||Av||^2 = ||\lambda v||^2 = |\lambda|^2||v||^2$

then somehow I want to cancel the $A$ so i'm left with $||v||^2 = |\lambda|^2||v||^2$ which would then leave me with $|\lambda|^2=1$ but I'm not sure how to do the intermediate step to get there?

Comment: Note that $|\lambda|^2 = 1$ is not enough information to deduce that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** First of all, continue your proof by noting that $\|Av\| = \|v\|$ due to the orthogonality of $A$.

Then, make the following observation. Let $\langle u,v \rangle$ denote the "dot product" of $u$ and $v$. If $Av = \lambda v$, note that the symmetry of $A$ implies that
$$
\langle Av, v \rangle = \langle v, Av \rangle.
$$
On the other hand, $\langle u, v \rangle = \overline{\langle v, u \rangle}$.

Comment: what does the bar mean?

Comment: @Dawa It means the complex conjugate. $\overline{a + bi} = a - bi$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, you are using $\lambda \overline{\lambda}\langle v,v\rangle=\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle AA^Tv,v\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle$ implies $\lambda \overline{\lambda}=1$

and $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$.

Comment: what does the bar mean?

Comment: @Dawa, is mean conjugate number, so $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$ only happen when $\lambda$ is a real number.